# Firefox svg rendering glitch

Tags: firefox, d3.js, svg

I've run into an issue on older versions of firefox, (in particular 38.2.1)
where a D3 animation of and SVG component results in rendering issues ( looks like its just not repainting the background).

a Minimal example below
https://jsfiddle.net/4n2f9g81/2/

```
<svg width="600" height="600">
  <g transform="translate(36, 24)">
    <g class="group" transform="translate(200)" >
      <circle class="circle" fill="white" r="20" stroke-width="2" stroke="#7ab800"></circle>
      <g class="label" >
        <line y1="-25" y2="-40" stroke="#7ab800" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></line>
        <text text-anchor="middle" class="peer-label position" y="-45" style="-moz-opacity:0">label text</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>


d3.select('.group').transition().duration(5000).attr("transform", "translate(0,100)");
```

It only occurs when the g element with the class label has some content.. if it's empty or hidden there's no corruption and the animation works fine. since it works in more recent version (and in other browsers) I assume I've hit a firefox bug which has since been resolved.

I'd like to know if there's a workaround for this on these older versions.  I've tried a couple of things like forcing a background fill or forcing opacity, but not had any success as yet.

Comment: Firefox 38.2.1 went end of life in the middle od 2016 and is now full of know unpatched security vulnerabilities. You need to upgrade to Firefox 45 ESR and stop supporting and deploying Firefox 38.2.1 asap. There will be no fixes to Firefox 38.2.1 bugs.

Comment: Thank's robert, very sensible advice and I agree. but the reality of corporate intranets is that it's fairly amazing that they even have firefox, let  alone a version that's less than a year old.   Besides  that if we take the logic we shouldn't write code for anything with a known vulnerability then we should only ever use the most recent version v50?

Comment: 45 ESR is updated with security fixes too.